# Understanding Sort on query in solr

Tags: sorting, solr, solr-query-syntax

I am new to solr and trying to understand a solr sort criteria that goes like this -

```
bQ01=2859969
bQ02={!term f=prdId v=$bQ01}
bQ03={!lucene} {!v=$bQ02}^=6

buryClearanceQuery={!parent which=$pq score=min v=$matchAllQueryRef2}
matchAllQueryRef2= ({!query v=$cq})  ({!simpleFilter v=$priceTypeClearance})
priceTypeClearance={!term f=priceType_refine v=$matchAllQueryRef3} 
matchAllQueryRef3=Clearance
cq= {!simpleFilter v=docType:pdf}   {!docValues v='shelf_873:1'}
sort=query($bQ03,0) desc, query($buryClearanceQuery) asc
```

I am facing issues understanding how the sort criteria is made above and how will `query(some_expression, 0) desc` will work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to the `sort` clause get there via parameter passing. So, basically in the Solr query you could reference it via `$` sign.

Simpler example from the Solr [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/local-parameters-in-queries.html#parameter-dereferencing)

```
q={!type=dismax qf=myfield v=$qq}&qq=solr rocks
```

Similar stuff is happening in your query and in sort clause particularly. [Sorting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/common-query-parameters.html#sort-parameter) by query is working as following:

> Solr can sort query responses according to document scores or the
>   value of any field with a single value

than in the `sort` clause you could specify the field by which you're sorting, or the query (it could be either normal query or [function query](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html)) - which produce single "pseudo" field (score)

Comment: can you please elaborate how 'query(some_expression, 0) desc' works?